# Confused about creating object "types" (?) in Javascript, like those used by People API in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script, types, google-people-api

**Update**
What I want is exactly the same as a named struct in C++.
You can define an object, give it a name, and treat it as a type.
Then you can declare multiple variables of that type.
This page describes named structures about halfway down:
https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_structs.asp

**Original Question**

I'm really new to Javascript; I come from more of a C++ background. I'm really confused by how to create object types, or whether "type" is even the right term in Javascript.

For example, the Google People API uses a bunch of specific objects that have clearly defined structures. Searches return a [Person](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person) object or an array of them. A Person object contains arrays of many other objects, such as [Name](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Name). These act like what I would think of as a datatype in another language, in that you can have multiple instances of them, all with the same data structure. Autosuggest even suggests keys for them.

I want to be able to create entities like this, that have a defined data structure and can have multiple instances. I looked at using classes, but wasn't sure that was the right solution.

As a corollary, how would I even go about making a new object of People.Person, or Person.Name, for example?

I'm sorry if this is annoyingly basic, but if anyone could suggest the right direction here I'd be grateful.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the result you want to need. For example, about `As a corollary, how would I even go about making a new object of People.Person, or Person.Name, for example?`, in this case, what result do you want? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Same question as Tanaike asked, I would like to know as well what is the intention of creating an object with named properties in them? Also for starters, kindly read on how [Javascript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) works.

Comment: @CenturyTuna What I want is basically the same as a named struct in C++.  https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_structs.asp

The objects that the People API works with behave just like that. A Person object named aPerson will have, for example, a field aPerson.names which is an array of Name objects. A Name object called aName will have the fields aName.givenName, aName.familyName, etc. These fields are writable and readable.

Comment: @CenturyTuna I want to do this for the same reason the People API does it: to bundle related information into a single object that I can pass as the return value of a function.

I have no idea how the People API defines these object types.

Comment: @CenturyTuna One use case I have for this is to make my own simplified person object that I can put data from a People API Person object into. For instance, I could do myPerson.name = aPerson.names[0].displayName, where myPerson is an object of my own type, and aPerson is a People API Person object.

Comment: @CenturyTuna Does this make sense? Let me know if there's anything unclear. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @Tanaike Do the responses I have to CenturyTuna make sense to you?

Comment: @Tanaike I just want to do the same thing as a named struct in C++.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing here are some key points that need to be discussed. 
1. The properties defined in the People API is a preset property generated by Google itself to define any information related to the user account based on the methods available. 
2. If we are talking about data types, Javascript automatically detects data as an object if it is wrapped in curly braces, and the objects and properties should be in a key value pair. Data types for Javascript are var, let, and const which have different use cases as well

Comment: I would suggest you look at this article, to start.  [Javascript Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)

Comment: @TheWizEd I have looked at it. As far as I can tell, that allows you to create a single object. That's not what I want at all. Have you used a named struct in C++? You can define a datatype (similar to a Javascript Object), name it, and declare variables of that type. As many as you wish. That's what I want.

Comment: @CenturyTuna 1) Exactly. How does Google itself create preset properties for predefined object types? That's what I want to do. Exactly like a named struct in C++. 2) I understand how to create an object. I'm asking how to create a TYPE of object that you can declare multiple instances of. Again...like a named struct in C++.

Comment: @CenturyTuna If you're not familiar with C++, this page describes named structures about halfway down. You can define an object, give it a name, and it becomes a type. Then you can declare multiple variables of that type.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @Quentin Ah, I think that's it. As usual, I feel dumb. Thank you.
Want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> Classes are a template for creating objects. They encapsulate data with code to work on that data.

Comment: I see that, yes, but I don't need methods, and I want to be able to assign data to keys using the same syntax as an an object literal. I also need to be able to use Object.values() to get an array of the values. I really just want to define an object of key:value pairs that I can declare instances of, and that can't be modified.